# Reverse proxy multiple tomcats on same nginx on same server

Tags: tomcat, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two different versions of tomcat running on my server and i am using nginx to reverse proxy my traffic on default 80 port. Now in my server block i cannot have tow locations /. I tried to change default root url of tomcat within its server.xml using Context element as below.

and then have my server block as:

## Tomcat 7 Homepage

```
location /tomsev {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }   

    # Tomcat 8 Homepage
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9506;
    }
```

This loads all the UI placed in tomcat 8 but not in 7. Now i also have a servlet application which is deployed on tomcat 7. After many trials and errors i finaly managed to get the page loaded but am unable to load the css, js, mime files. They all throw unable to load resources error. My application url is:
http://myserver.com/myapplication/landingPage.do

Tomact 7:
deployed the application war file in its webapp folder.

Nginx config file:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name myserver.com;

    # Tomcat 8 Homepage
    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9506;
    }

    location /myapplication/ {
      proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapplication/landingPage.do;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
location /tomsev/ {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
   sub_filter_once off;
   sub_filter '<head>' '<head>\n<base href="/tomsev/">';
}
```

Basically your want to change the base url. You can either change that using nginx filter. Or you need to adjust tomcat to use a baseurl. See below for more details on that

https://serverfault.com/questions/380200/adding-a-global-uri-prefix-for-tomcat-web-apps

If you change the base dir of the tomcat then the config will change like below

```
location /tomsev/ {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/tomsev/;
}
```

And the basedir in tomcat server should be `tomsev`

Comment: thanks a lot. the second solution worked for me. am now able to load the application. Much appreciated.